# Java Grpc server behind the Traefik proxy

Tags: grpc, traefik, grpc-java, grpc-web

This is my traefik configuration

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":81"

[file]
 [backends]
   [backends.backend1]
     [backends.backend1.servers.server1]
     url = "h2c://10.141.11.230:6566"
 [frontends]
   [frontends.frontend1]
   entryPoints = ["http"]
   backend = "backend1"
```

When grpc server is being invoked by js web client via traefik proxy, I'm getting this warning on server side

```
WARN 22160 --- [-worker-ELG-3-1] io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler         : Expected header TE: trailers, but null is received. This means some intermediate proxy may not support trailers
```

The service method is not invoked.

Client get's  `415 (Unsupported Media Type)` response.

Traefik `1.7.16`

Grpc-java `1.22.1`

grpc-web@1.0.6

What am I missing ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TE: trailers` warning is a false alarm in your situation; [I've created a grpc-java PR](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/pull/6194) to prevent it in the future.

The `415` is the true failure. That means that the client is using a content-type that isn't `application/grpc`. This is because grpc-web uses an alternate protocol which needs to be converted. Converting the protocol is typically done with a proxy; that's what the Envoy proxy does that's mentioned on the [grpc-web repository](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web).

Comment: Thanks, I was under impression that traefik translates http to http2 like envoy does. Found an open  issue about supporting the conversion in their repository....

Comment: This is different from HTTP to HTTP/2. This is the grpc protocol formatting. grpc-web supports a plain-text encoding (for IE) and also avoids using trailers. See https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/PROTOCOL-WEB.md#protocol-differences-vs-grpc-over-http2